# Website certificate "marked as not trusted" despite being, in fact, marked as trusted

Tags: safari, security, keychain

There's a particular website which I use a lot (university-related) and has given me grief with its certificate for years now. I oscillate between periods of indignation and attempts at troubleshooting it and periods of quiet resignation. I'm hoping someone here will have a solution for me.

The specific problem I have is that Safari refuses to trust the certificate. When I first visite the website, I get the standard "certificate not trusted" message and am asked whether I want to review the certificate settings or just proceed to visit the website. Clicking on the link to visit the website merely reloads the page for me.

This is what the certificate for the website in question looks like:

[image]

I don't understand how it can be "marked as not trusted" when every option is set to "Always Trust".

Oddly enough, if I open a private window and navigate to the site, clicking on the link to visit the website actually loads the website without a problem (once I enter my username and password, as it's a password-protected website). After that, I can visit the website on non-private windows, although I'll be asked for my username and password again the first time I do so (obviously, since cookies aren't shared between private and non-private windows). This lasts until I quit Safari, at which point I'm back to it not working on non-private windows.

Previous (failed) attempts at solving the problem have involved clearing the Safari cache and deleting all cookies, as well as deleting all KeyChain items related to the website in question.

Other browsers don't give me this problem; even Safari on mobile behaves properly. The problem is specific to Safari on Mac. I'm currently using Safari 13.0.1 on Mojave (macOS 10.14.6). However, the problem isn't specific to these versions of Safari and macOS/OSX; I've had it since Sierra and Safari 11.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please include the URL for that web site so that we can see the actual details of the certificate. The information in your screenshot is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying; I was out of town. The URL is  https://langsrv.astro.cf.ac.uk.